# OpenCV- Convert mat image type from CV_8UC4 to CV_16UC3

Tags: opencv

I need to convert OpenCV different types like `CV_8UC4` to `CV_16UC3`.

I tried `convertTo(mat, CV_16UC3)`, but this is returns an empty image (when I save it to the storage it's empty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`convertTo` can't change the number of channels.

You'll need two steps:

1. `cv::cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGRA2BGR)`
2. `dst.convertTo(mat, CV_16U)`

for example if your 4th channel is an alpha channel and you just want to drop it.

Comment: `convertTo` doesn't need the number of channels. Hope you don't mind ;D